# Timing issue? Program runs fine in Visual Studio but not standalone

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I have a native C++ DLL.  The DLL creates a thread which repeatedly reads data from an external device.  If data is not read quickly enough, the device can overflow.

The 'read' loop looks something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    read_from_device();

    buffer_data();

    Sleep(5);  //Allow data to accumulate 
}
```

I also have a C# application which utilises the above DLL.  It calls a function in the DLL to kick off the 'read' thread, and then periodically calls another function in the DLL to check whether all the data has been read from the external device.

Both the application and the DLL are built in 'Debug' mode in Visual Studio (2008 in this case).

If I run the application through Visual Studio everything is fine:  data is read from the external device and no overflows occur.

When I run the same application 'standalone' (by directly running the .exe), I encounter overflows.

I think the only difference is that in the first instance the Visual Studio debugger is automatically attached to the application?  Bear in mind I have no breakpoints set.

There must be a timing issue present in my application which is somehow rectified when the debugger is attached to it?

How on earth can I go about debugging this problem?

What other differences are there between running an application via Visual Studio and running it directly?

**EDIT**:

Here is the code in more detail:

```
int buffer[MAX_EVENTS*2];
int bufferIndex = 0;
int eventsReturned = 0;

BufferObject *pNewBuffer;

while (bPollData)
{
    read_data(buffer[bufferIndex], &eventsReturned);

    bufferIndex += eventsReturned;

    if (bufferIndex >= MAX_EVENTS)
    {
        pNewBuffer = new BufferObject(buffer, bufferIndex);

        myList.AddTail(pNewBuffer);

        bufferIndex = 0;
    }

    Sleep(5);
}

...
... 

class BufferObject {
    int *buffer;
    int bufferSize;
public:
    BufferObject(int* source, int size)
    {
        buffer = new int[size];
        bufferSize = size;
        memcpy(buffer, source, size);
    }
};
```

Comment: Usually related to memory. Anyway, we need see more code.

Comment: Are you compiling your DLL with optimizations? Have you tried remove the sleep even though it works fine when is attached to VS?

Comment: Check windows log for error that caused crash

Comment: Why do you have a sleep there at all? Surely if you want to avoid overflows you should read as fast as possible. As an aside, you would be better off having your read loop checking a manual reset event so that you can cleanly shut your thread down when you're done...

Comment: @LenHolgate The sleep is there to allow data to accumulate.  If I read from the device too often the device spends all its time servicing requests instead of collecting data.  The thread does actually have a nicer way of shutting down, I just didn't include it.

Comment: We need to see more code. Specifically how the dll allows the application to access the buffer that it's reading data from the device into. So ideally we need to see the code that puts that data into the dll's buffer and the code that takes the data out of the dll's buffer.

Comment: Sorry it's late, but I've added some more detailed code.  Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3):

```
   Sleep(5);
```

Well, that is 99% of your problem right there.  You already *know* that you have a problem when your code runs fast.  You artificially slowed it down to put a band-aid on the bug.  But of course should not be surprised that it breaks again when you do something *else* that makes your code run faster.  Like not running it with a debugger attached.

You probably don't even know for a fact that 5 is adequate.  It is a pretty random number and the amount of time your program will *actually* sleep is very rarely exactly 5 milliseconds.  Default sleep accuracy is 15.625 msec but that can change when another program calls timeBeginPeriod().  Just running a browser is enough, Chrome notoriously changes the interrupt rate.  So instead of 15 msec you suddenly run 3 times faster.  Breaking your program.  You don't want Chrome to break your program ;)

You have to tackle the *real* problem.  Which surely is something like you just taking however many bytes the device sent you and putting it in a BufferObject.  So if your program runs fast, you get *many* buffer objects, each with but a little bit of data.  That can cause havoc on whatever code that consumes the data.  A traditional problem is the UI of the program going catatonic, madly trying to keep up with the required repaints.

Without nearly enough insight from the question, a random guess is that you must buffer the device response first until it accumulated enough bytes to make it worthwhile to stick it in a BufferObject.  If you continue with the Sleep() band-aid then pick a sleep amount that's an integer multiple of 15.625 rounded down.  Like 15, 31, 46.

Comment: Just this very minute I was logging the time between calls to the read_data() function and was getting 156000us.  I wasn't aware of that.  If I remove the Sleep(n), the device spends all of its time servicing read_data() requests which adversely affects its other (main) task of collecting data.  So I need to somehow restrict the frequency of calls to read_data().  Many thanks for your answer, it may allow me to progress.

Comment: Does the device collect at a constant or variable rate? You could try dynamically tuning the delay based on the number of data points that are returned. So if it returns more than X from one call you call it immediately again else you wait ...

Answer (score 2):

You're likely suffering from lack of synchronisation between the thread that is collecting the data (and building the list of buffers) and the thread that the application uses to access (and presumably remove) the buffers.

You likely need to include some locking around access to the buffer list. It seems that you have an "active" buffer which only the data reader thread can write into (buffer) and when this is full you copy this data into a new buffer object and add it to the list. You should likely lock around the use of the list (the list may include correct synchronisation internally but it's unclear from your code example).

There appears to be no way for the loop to inform the read_data() function of the remaining space in the buffer it passes in, this may be a cause of memory overruns which could be causing problems.

Personally, since you're dynamically allocating buffer objects anyway, I'd skip the memory copy entirely and simply hold an active buffer object and read into that directly rather than into a temporary buffer which you then copy into a buffer object.

It's impossible to do more than guess given the nature of the question and the lack of code.

Comment: Thanks Len.  The list is never actually accessed concurrently so I don't need to lock access to it - however I'm at my wit's end with this so I'll give it a try anyway.  I'll also take another look at the read_data() aspect of the code.

Your point about the superfluous memory copy is a good one, I'll certainly make that change.

I appreciate it's difficult to assess the problem due the lack of code, but my initial thought was that the code was actually sound and it was merely the presence or not of the debugger that was altering the timing of the application. I hadn't considered memory issues

Comment: @digital_fate: Note that if your code fails because the debugger changes the timing, the code is *not* sound. It should work independent of exact timings -- Windows is not a real-time operating system and it can't give you any guarantees. Today it's the debugger changing the timing, tomorrow it's Windows Update.

Comment: Jeroen, or, most likely, simply running it on a different machine :)